# metodo async dentro de un controller, webApi

Tags: c#, webapi

espero se logre entender mi pregunta.
Desde una aplicación Angular estoy consumiendo un servicio, el servicio espera
la respuesta de otra URL y dependiendo de esa respuesta se deben ejecutar ciertas instrucciones pero de manera ASYNCRONA, por ejemplo si la respuesta es "true" entonces se ejecutan 3 instrucciones de manera asyncrona.
Lo he intentado pero me sale un error que detallo mas abajo.
(**Notese que es un ejemplo de prueba**)

- controlador

[image: imagen de controlador]

- metodo pruebaAsync

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- metodo Asyncrono: accionTrue (metodo accion 1 es igual a accion2 y accion3)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- error que lanza PostMan

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muy buenas, te recomendaría que editases la pregunta y añadieses el código en lugar de imágenes, ya que si alguien quiere probarlo para poder ayudarte le sea lo mas cómodo posible, y por tanto, tengas mas posibilidades de tener una respuesta adecuada. Un saludo

Comment: Muy buena observación, para mis próximas preguntas aplicare tu consejo, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que tener en cuenta que si un método es asíncrono la forma de esperar que ese método termine es usando await.

Si vemos tu función pruebaAsync no utilizas await para el método asíncrono accionTrue() por lo que la función devolverá "hola" y no esperara a que termine el método accionTrue por eso te da el error.

Entonces tienes que hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
public async string pruebaAsync (){
   bol result = true;
   if (result){
      await accionTrue();
   }
   return "hola";
}
```

Espero que te funcione y entiendas el porque del  error.

Comment: No era la solución directamente, pero me abriste los ojos y la pude encontrar MUCHAS GRACIAS, TE PASASTE!!